# How to export (only) canvas as an image

Tags: java, image, swing, canvas, bufferedimage

I want to export an image painted on a canvas to a PNG or JPEG file. I found solutions that allow me to export the whole JPanel, but that's not what I want. When I try to export the canvas, the image I get has the right size but is completely black.

Here is my code:

```
public void exportImage(String imageName) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) canvas.getGraphics();
    paint(graphics);
    graphics.dispose();
    try {
        System.out.println("Exporting image: " + imageName);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageName);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This is
[my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMvec.png)

And this is the
[canvas that should be exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLIg5.png)

Comment: You should be painting on a drawing `JPanel`.  The Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but I have a JPanel that containt buttons, labels, etc. In addition, there is a canvas on it, where you can paint on using your mouse (i'm making a paint-copy for a school project). I can export the whole JPanel (i wrote JFrame in my question, I apologise) as an image but i just want the canvas to be exported. Any other Ideas?

Comment: Sure.  Get rid of the canvas and use a drawing `JPanel`,

Comment: *"I know similar questions were already asked,"* Link the top three. *"but none of the answers helped me."* Why not? What would make someone who sees this question think they could post a solution you had not seen before and would help you? I for one, am outta' here until there is a much better, more answerable question. BTW - [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: BTW(2): I suspect `canvas.getGraphics();` needs to be `image.getGraphics();` - but post that MRE.